# Plone combining several behaviors into one fieldset

Tags: plone, behavior, dexterity

I'm wondering if it is possible to combine several behaviors, which come with their defined fieldsets into one schemata. For example there are Dublin Core fields `ICategorization`, `IPublication`, `IOwnership` and they all come with their own fieldsets, what makes them appear on different tabs in form edit. I would like to have one tab with all of their fields combined. I've tried to overwrite `IDublinCore` specifying my own fieldset with fields I want, and that gave me everything what I wanted in one tab, however, other tabs were still present.. So I've tried in my own interface to overwrite those as well with:

```
form.fieldset('ownership', fields=[])
```

however, `Ownership` tab was still present.

Comment: plone.directives.form hints are set on the class using zope.schema and zope.annoatations. You may modify this information run-time and "fix" it by hand if there are no functions available to do it with higher level APIs.

Comment: http://developer.plone.org/misc/annotations.html?highlight=annotations and http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html#tagged-values